# Error when sending firebase-messaging push notifications

Tags: c#, firebase, minimal-apis

Good afternoon, I can't send push notifications when starting the server on a remote PC.
On local PC everything works and push notifications are successfully processed and sent.
But when I run the `.exe` of my minimal API on the remote server, I get the following error:

> FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.FirebaseMessagingException: Unknown error while
> making a remote service call: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
> ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
> ---> System.IO.IOException:  Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.
> at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReceiveBlobAsync[TIOAdapter](CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Maybe there are some conditions that need to be met for this service to work on a remote pc? I have looked that this service "runs" on port 443, ports are open, certificates are installed, but the error does not disappear, maybe someone has encountered something like this?
Thanks